# How to go around the problem of using np.loadtxt() if my data contains strings

Tags: python, numpy, load

I want to use the funcion loadtxt from numpy, however, my txt data contains strings in it. How could I ignore the strings and still maintain the rows and columns of my data?

```
import os
from numpy import loadtxt

filename = 'C:/Users/.../Documents/.../.../.../.../.../.../report.txt'

data = loadtxt(filename)

# That's a sample of the data I am trying to load

1 stats/cope1 2589 -3.519 -0.8423 0.02977 -0.1044 1.133 4.889 0.9278 61 29 14 7.0 -90.6 -9.4
1 stats/cope2 2589 -4.102 -1.134 -0.04528 -0.1969 1.468 8.227 1.194 61 30 15 7.0 -88.2 -6.3
```

The output:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: stats/pe1
```

Comment: You are going to have to somehow extract the relevant portions of your file. Without a [mcve] it's impossible to say.

Comment: Did you  try the `usecols` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = np.genfromtxt('filename', dtype='str')
data = np.delete(data, 1, 1)
data = [[float(i) for i in data[0]],[float(i) for i in data[1]]]  # type: list
data = np.asarray(data)  # type: numpy.ndarray

data.shape  # (2,10)

print(data)  
# array([[1., 1.133, 4.889, 0.9278, 61., 29. ,14., 7., -90.6 ,  -9.4],
#        [1., 1.468, 8.227, 1.194 , 61., 30., 15., 7., -88.2 ,  -6.3]])
```